# Combinatorics: relations and cardinality.

Tags: combinatorics

part a)$N=\{1,2,...100\}$ and define relation $R$ on $N$ as follows $aRb$ if $|a-b|=9 $
I have solved this and come to the conclusion that it is not an equivalence relation as it is not reflexive.

I am stuck on the next part. 
part b) let A be contained in $N$ and $\#A=55$, show that A contains two numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a-b= 9.$ Hint: use the rule of double counting.

Now im under the impression that the rule of double counting says that if two things are incident then the set of those incident to b is equal to those incident to a or somehting of the sort. I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: Thank you for participating on this website, you've put some of your thoughts into this question and we are ready to prod you. I appreciate you and welcome you to mathstack! Please, next time though, try to write up your mathematical expressions in LaTeX. (It is not that big of a deal in this case, because it your question was easy to follow, but as a general rule--try to do it for every question).

Comment: I really struggle with latex unfortunately though it gets me a lot of 'flack' here. i thought it wouldnt be too bad as this wasnt too complicated of an equation.

Comment: You're exactly right, in this case it definitely could have been omitted because your question was easy to read. As a general rule of thumb though, try to incorporate latex whenever you can. There is a **great** tutorial in the meta that will show you how to do latex on this site. I will try to find it so that you won't get as much 'flack'.

Comment: Here is the tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Add $9$ to each of the elements of $A$ and call this new set $B$. All numbers in $A$, which are less than $92$, result in another number in $N$ after this addition. So $B$ contains at least $46$ numbers within $N$. As $A$ itself has $55$ elements, at least one number in  $N$ must be present in both $A$ and $B$. This gives us a pair $a,b$ with $a-b=9$.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is not the proof intended by the author of the hint, but here goes anyway:

Define a function $f$ from $A$ to $N$ such that $f(x) = x + 9$ when $x \le 91$ and $f(x) = x - 9$ if $x > 91$. If $A$ contains no two numbers $a$ and $b$ with $|a-b|=9$, then $f(a) \not\in A$ for $a \in A$. I.e., $A$ is disjoint from the image of $f$. But, if $x \not= y$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ iff $|x - y| = 18$ and $\mbox{max}\{x, y\} > 91$, and there are only $9$ such pairs. If $A$ has 55 elements, then the image of $f$ must have at least $55 - 18 + 9 = 46$ elements which is impossible as $N$ has only $100$ elements$.